# Graphical glitch on UITableView when reloading a section

Tags: ios, uitableview

Basically looking for clues/hints from anyone who may have experienced something similar. The graphical glitch/flicker occurs when I perform update a section of a UITableView. You can see this on the image below.

[image: Glitch]

My refresh code looks like this:

```
NSInteger sectionIndex = [self getSectionListIndexForID:sectionName];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

My table data, state, height, etc. is backed by dictionaries which I query for how to display the sections and cells. I basically update the dictionaries on the switch event and call the code above.

---

**Edit**

This is what it looked like if I removed the setAnimationsEnabled call.

[image]

---

**Edit**

More clues. The "frame" of the cell as it its layoutSubviews is being called during the switch animation looks like its offset by 64 pixels for one frame (the size of the nav). Slowly hunting this down...

---

**Edit**

Somewhere between the call to toggleSendAction and performWithoutAnimation, the cell's frame is offset by 64 pixels.

[image]

Comment: How many times does your update code run per click of the switch? Also, what if you remove the _setAnimationsEnabled:_ calls?

Comment: Are you implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath and estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath? If so, can you show the code?

Comment: @nielsbot Update code is run once. I removed the animation calls and that might hint as to what is going on. I will update the question with the animated gif of what happens.

Comment: @juanjo I do implement heightForRowAtIndexPath. It basically uses a dictionary keyed to the index path to return the height. I do not implement estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: and you do this on the main thread?

Comment: @nielsbot If by this you mean my refresh code, then no. Its called as part of a button target. I tried putting it in [NSOperationQueue mainQueue block, but it still works the same. juanjo might be right in that its a height/position type issue causing the incorrect animation to occur.

Comment: button actions happen on the main thread

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you solve it?